# Matrix of operands and operators

Tags: algorithm

This is my first ever question here.

I have a matrix 5x5 like this :

```
 a + b * c
 * d + f +
 g * h + i
 + j + k *
 l + m * n
```

Can someone help me to find an algorithm to find all the math operations possible in this matrix?

Comment: Please precisely define a "math operation"? What rules should we adhere to?

Comment: You need to be more clear as to what you're looking for. Are you actually asking about Java, or is your question independent of language?

Comment: Please list all math operations that are possible in this example.

Comment: Do you mean, "an algorithm to find all the columns and rows that would represent valid arithmetic expressions?"  You haven't really defined what you want very well.  There is a tag for algorithms, btw.  This is tagged for Java, but has nothing to do with Java, really.

Comment: Also, what have you tried so far ?

Comment: When you say math operations, do you mean stuff like "+" and "*" or do you mean "a+b" and also "a+b+c"?

Comment: Would be "a+b+d*a" (uses `a` twice) allowed? Do we have to use all variables in every formula?

Comment: Also, define what happens when there is a syntax error, for example, a variable 'a' appears twice, or a division by zero.

Comment: And finally, what do you have against `e`?

Comment: Guys I am sorry. I was not precise and I beg your pardon!!!In this matrix I am not inserting division and subtraction since a-b is different tha b-a. My matrix will have only + and * so far but if I will able to get an algorithm to find sequence of all operations then I might add / and -. For sequence I mean like: a+b, a*d, a*b + d and so on. I tried to make a Graph but did not find a way to get out of that..Hope that my explanation can be clear enoght to shed the light to the problem. Thanks

Comment: Um, where's that `a * b + d` coming from? I only see a possible `a + b` in the matrix. But I'm not Neo...

Comment: Sorry, this is still not too clear and unlikely to help other visitors, voting to close. And the number of answers would likely be (close to) infinite as well.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming only straight lines are allowed: first make a list of all 10 columns and rows, like this:

```
a + b * c
* d + f +
g * h + i
+ j + k *
l + m * n
a * g + l
+ d * j +
b + h + m
* f + k *
c + i * n
```

Chop off the unusable operators at the edges:

```
a + b * c
d + f
g * h + i
j + k
l + m * n
a * g + l
d * j
b + h + m
f + k
c + i * n
```

Then:

- for each entry of the form `x ∙ y`, evaluate `x`, `y`, and `x ∙ y`, and
- for each entry of the form `x ∙ y ∙ z`, evaluate `x`, `y`, `z`, `x ∙ y`, `y ∙ z`, and `x ∙ y ∙ z`.

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer. Not only linear operations are allowed.Even a *d*g is a valid operation, beacuse I need to know exactly all the operations in this matrix.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this but here is how I would go about this: ( I provided a sample code in java for you but you should be able to implement this in other languages too)

- create a Multi-Dimensional array  to hold your values in there
- loop though the Multi-Dimensional and see if each value is a math operation character.

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      char[ ][ ] aryChar = new char[5][5];
      aryChar[0][0] = 'a';
      aryChar[0][1] = '+';
      aryChar[0][2] = 'b';
      aryChar[0][3] = '*';
      aryChar[0][4] = 'c';

  ```
  aryChar[1][0] = '*';
  aryChar[1][1] = 'd';
  aryChar[1][2] = '+';
  aryChar[1][3] = 'f';
  aryChar[1][4] = '+';


  aryChar[2][0] = 'g';
  aryChar[2][1] = '*';
  aryChar[2][2] = 'h';
  aryChar[2][3] = '+';
  aryChar[2][4] = 'i';

  aryChar[3][0] = '+';
  aryChar[3][1] = 'j';
  aryChar[3][2] = '+';
  aryChar[3][3] = 'k';
  aryChar[3][4] = '*';

  aryChar[4][0] = 'l';
  aryChar[4][1] = '+';
  aryChar[4][2] = 'm';
  aryChar[4][3] = '*';
  aryChar[4][4] = 'n';

  int rows=5;
  int columns=5;
  int i, j;


  for (i=0; i < rows ; i++) {

      for (j=0; j < columns ; j++) {

          //you can add more || to add other math operations 
          if(aryChar[ i ][ j ]=='*' ||aryChar[ i ][ j ]=='+'   ){
              System.out.print("found math operations");
              System.out.print( aryChar[ i ][ j ] + " " +"\n");
          }
      }

  }

  System.out.println( "" );
  ```

  }

Comment: Sorry mate , I was not clear. My question is to find all the patterns of operations possibile in this Matrix like : 1) a+b 2)a+b*c 3)a+d4)a*d and so on...